# Best way to run Robolectric tests on Android device

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I have a Robolectric test project setup, but I'd like to also run these tests on my device to check that I don't get bit by JVM vs Dalvik implementation differences.

Unlike robolectric tests, I won't run these tests frequently. My concern is that there's little effort to maintain the test suite and that they verify actual device functionality.

What's the best way to do that?

---

What I've currently got:

My robolectric test project as a test case TestPackage. I created an Android Test project with a test case TestRoboOnAndroid. It creates a TestPackage and has a test for each test in TestPackage.

Right now, every time I add a test to my robolectric suite, I need to manually add it to my device suite. Is there some way to do that automatically with reflection?

Also, Robolectric uses JUnit 4 (by default) and Android uses JUnit 3. So I have to write all of my Robolectric tests using JUnit 3 style (importing from `junit.framework` instead of `org.junit`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a tiered system, where I prefer earlier tiers where possible:

- *Pure unit tests*. I try to make as much code as possible fully independent of Android APIs, and then use "pure" unit tests which can run on any JVM. These tests are the fastest, and it helps keep code that has no need to be Android-specific portable.
- *Robolectric-supported unit tests*. Where my code has only small dependencies on Android APIs, that can be satisfied by Robolectric shadows, I test it with Robolectric. There is a little more setup time for Robolectric compared to pure tests, but it's still faster than starting/running on an emulator.
- *Android framework tests*. Where Robolectric doesn't cut it - either because the shadows don't exist, or because I'm heavily using Android APIs (and therefore want to test against the Real Thing) - I write test that run on the emulator/device with the default framework.

The point of the tiers is to keep things as simple as possible, which keeps the full suite faster and helps promote cleaner code.

Answer (score 12):

The whole point of Robolectric is NOT to run it on the device and the design is based on that. If you want to run something on the device look at the default instrumentation tests from the SDK or [Robotium](http://www.robotium.org).

It is totally feasible to run your Robolectric tests on the JVM and in addition create Robotium tests that rely on device specific interaction (e.g. creating screenshots, hardware differences...) and run on devices and emulators all combined into one build.

The easiest way to do that is to use the [Android Maven Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/).

Comment: It's not device issues I'm worried about. I was using a library (org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser) and the jar I had to run my Robotium tests was more lenient than the Android version. (I was using it wrong and my Robotium tests didn't detect my error because the tests ran different code than the device.) Instead of including my own jars for everything, I'd like to flip a switch to run my tests on a device. It doesn't need to be nice -- I'm not going to run it often. It just needs to help me keep my sanity.

Comment: did you actually deploy org.xmlpull in your apk onto the device? t otherwise that is not really possible. Basically is sounds like you have some wrong dependencies in test vs on device.. just fix these.

Comment: I think we're not on the same page. I'm not saying that I cannot run Robolectric tests on my device, just that it's inconvenient because I need to write a wrapper (containing a test for every test in my Robolectic suite). Yes, I could make sure my build prefers my xmlpull jar to the android one, but I discovered that problem by running my Robolectric tests on my device. See the chicken-and-egg problem?

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is completely reasonable to be able to expect to run the same tests on a real device rather than a mock environment, and for free. If you want to go by "the design is based on that" then I'll go with the junit design being based on using different test runners. I'm looking deeper into this and I'll post a real answer when I have one.

Comment: Great. I look forward to your results.

Comment: I tend to agree with Manfred that there's no point in running junit test on your device. You want to test your code, not your device. Robolectric mimics a device perfectly well, allowing you to mock certain classes, like httpClient. I'm very happy with the way Robolectric works.

Comment: @Christine, what use is code that passes tests yet doesn't run on your device?

Comment: @PiersyP, a unit test tests a small piece of your code. With a unit test, you want to confirm that that piece of code works ok. It doesn't matter where it runs, imho. Of course, if you can find a tool that lets you run unit tests on your device, that's great. I think it would make things overly complicated. Now, if a test runs fine but the code doesn't work on your device, then there's something wrong with your unit test tools. I have seen situations where a unit test in Robolectric behaves slightly different from running the same code on a device. I have always found a work-around or a fix.

Comment: @ManfredMoser you may want to revisit that first statement ;)
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/write-once-run-everywhere-tests-on-android-88adb2ba20c5

Answer (score 0):

We use Robolectric for unit testing against the JVM and Calabash-Android for system testing against Dalvik. Both can be integrated into our Jenkins CI build and between the two tools I feel that we cover all the bases.